# sql same table same column but two data

Tags: sql

TABLE1

```
     NAME

 1. AHMET
 2. MEHMET
 3. VELİ
 4. TEMEL
```

---

```
Select * from TABLE1 WHERE NAME='AHMET' and NAME='VELİ'
```

Comment: Is there a question in all of this? If not, I propose `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: AND operator means, both of the WHERE must be true to find a record, as you want to select multiple you will have to use either operator OR or you can use IN ('AHMET','VELI')

Comment: The same value can never simultaneously equal *two different things*.  Maybe you want to use `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probaly you want `IN` operator:

```
Select * from TABLE1 WHERE NAME IN('AHMET', 'VELİ')
```

Comment: I know very basic question but sometimes you cannot find because question is very very easy.Thanks.